# Rxjs Angular2: Want to understand what below code does

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am learning Angular2. I am following one of programming course where I came across following code in exercise files. I am facing difficulty understanding what the statement **".do(this.toggleLogState.bind(this));"** does? 
It would be really helpful if someone can explain it. Thanks in advance.

Please find the code below

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor(
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService,
    private userProfileService: UserProfileService) { }

  login() {
    return Observable.of(true)
        .do(_ => this.spinnerService.show())
        .delay(1000)
        .do(this.toggleLogState.bind(this)); // don't understand what this statement will do
  }

  logout() {
    this.toggleLogState(false);
  }

  private toggleLogState(val: boolean) {
    this.userProfileService.isLoggedIn = val;
    this.spinnerService.hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Which part of it you don't understand? It will call the method 1 second after `spinnerService.show()`

Comment: @echonax I have edited the question to make it clear. Basically I don't understand what ".do(this.toggleLogState.bind(this));" statement will do?

Comment: Did you not understand the bind part? As I've said it will call the `toggleLogState` method

Comment: @echonax what parameter toggleLogState function will get and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.do(this.toggleLogState.bind(this))
```

This is effectively the same as

```
.do(v => this.toggleLogState(v));
```

The lambda expression makes it so that `this` in `toggleLogState` is the instance of this class, which is what `.bind(this)` does as well.

`bind` also makes sure that any arguments are passed along to the given method. The parameter in this case comes from the observable. `Observable.of(true)` starts with a boolean value of `true`. `do(...)` and `delay(...)` always pass along the same parameter value that was passed into them. So by the end of this chain, you're passing along the `true` that you started with in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much now I understand this fully :)

Comment: @HirenGondhiya: Glad I could help. Make sure you mark the question answered so other people know you don't still need help.